# Image sequence to video stream?

Tags: c#, image, video, ffmpeg, aforge

Like many people already seem to have (there are several threads on this subject here) I am looking for ways to create video from a sequence of images.

I want to implement my functionality in C#!

Here is what I wan't to do:

```
/*Pseudo code*/
void CreateVideo(List<Image> imageSequence, long durationOfEachImageMs, string outputVideoFileName, string outputFormat)
{
    // Info: imageSequence.Count will be > 30 000 images
    // Info: durationOfEachImageMs will be < 300 ms

    if (outputFormat = "mpeg")
    {
    }
    else if (outputFormat = "avi")
    {      
    }
    else
    {
    }

    //Save video file do disk
}
```

I know there's a project called **Splicer** (http://splicer.codeplex.com/) but I can't find suitable documentation or clear examples that I can follow ([these](http://www.codeplex.com/Splicer/Wiki/View.aspx?title=News%20Feeds&referringTitle=Home) are the examples that I found).

The closest I want to do, which I find here on CodePlex is this:
[How can I create a video from a directory of images in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251467/how-can-i-create-a-video-from-a-directory-of-images-in-c)

I have also read a few threads about **ffmpeg** (for example this: [C# and FFmpeg preferably without shell commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707516/c-sharp-and-ffmpeg-preferably-without-shell-commands) and this: [convert image sequence using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275865/convert-image-sequence-using-ffmpeg)) but I find no one to help me with my problem and I don't think **ffmpeg**-command-line-style is the best solution for me (because of the amount of images).

I believe that I can use the **Splicer**-project in some way (?).

In my case, it is about about > 30 000 images where each image should be displayed for about 200 ms (in the videostream that I want to create).

(What the video is about? Plants growing ...)

Can anyone help me complete my function?

Comment: There is a good 3rd party toolkit named leadtools that might help you. This toolkit gives you the ability to generate a video file from a sequence of images. For details, see this link:
http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/16880/ShowPost.aspx

Comment: Not free LeadTools. Any final solution with full source code?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with @Kiquenet?

Comment: Just as an aside, don't use strings for your image format, use an Enum. It's what they're for....

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Well, this answer comes a bit late, but since I have noticed some activity with my original question lately (and the fact that there was not provided a working solution) I would like to give you what finally worked for me.

I'll split my answer into three parts:

- Background
- Problem
- Solution

---

### Background

(this section is not important for the solution)

My original problem was that I had a lot of images (i.e. a huge amount), images that were individually stored in a database as byte arrays. *I wanted to make a video sequence with all these images.*

My equipment setup was something like this general drawing:
[image]

The images depicted growing tomato plants in different states. All images were taken every 1 minute under daytime.

```
/*pseudo code for taking and storing images*/
while (true)
{
    if (daylight)
    {
        //get an image from the camera
        //store the image as byte array to db
    }
    //wait 1 min
}
```

I had a very simple db for storing images, there were only one table (the table ImageSet) in it:
[image]

---

### Problem

I had read many articles about ffmpeg (please see my original question) but I couldn't find any on how to go from a collection of images to a video.

---

### Solution

Finally, I got a working solution!
The main part of it comes from the open source project [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/). In short, you could say that [AForge.NET is a computer vision and artificial intelligence library in C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AForge.NET).
(If you want a copy of the framework, just grab it from http://www.aforgenet.com/)

In AForge.NET, there is this VideoFileWriter class (a class for writing videofiles with help of ffmpeg). This did almost all of the work. (There is also a very good example [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4ee1742c-44d3-b250-d6aa-90cd2d606611.htm))

This is the final class (reduced) which I used to fetch and convert image data into a video from my image database:

```
public class MovieMaker
{

    public void Start()
    {
        var startDate = DateTime.Parse("12 Mar 2012");
        var endDate = DateTime.Parse("13 Aug 2012");

        CreateMovie(startDate, endDate);
    }    
    

    /*THIS CODE BLOCK IS COPIED*/

    public Bitmap ToBitmap(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        var returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(returnImage);

        return bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap ReduceBitmap(Bitmap original, int reducedWidth, int reducedHeight)
    {
        var reduced = new Bitmap(reducedWidth, reducedHeight);
        using (var dc = Graphics.FromImage(reduced))
        {
            // you might want to change properties like
            dc.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            dc.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, reducedWidth, reducedHeight), new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        return reduced;
    }

    /*END OF COPIED CODE BLOCK*/


    private void CreateMovie(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        int width = 320;
        int height = 240;
        var framRate = 200;

        using (var container = new ImageEntitiesContainer())
        {
            //a LINQ-query for getting the desired images
            var query = from d in container.ImageSet
                        where d.Date >= startDate && d.Date <= endDate
                        select d;

            // create instance of video writer
            using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
            {
                // create new video file
                vFWriter.Open("nameOfMyVideoFile.avi", width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.Raw);

                var imageEntities = query.ToList();

                //loop throught all images in the collection
                foreach (var imageEntity in imageEntities)
                {
                    //what's the current image data?
                    var imageByteArray = imageEntity.Data;
                    var bmp = ToBitmap(imageByteArray);
                    var bmpReduced = ReduceBitmap(bmp, width, height);

                    vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bmpReduced);
                }
                vFWriter.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Update 2013-11-29** (how to) (Hope this is what you asked for @Kiquenet?)

1. Download AForge.NET Framework from the [downloads page](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html) (Download full ZIP archive and you will find many interesting Visual Studio solutions with projects, like Video, in the `AForge.NET Framework-2.2.5\Samples folder`...)
2. Namespace:  `AForge.Video.FFMPEG` (from the [documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4ee1742c-44d3-b250-d6aa-90cd2d606611.htm))
3. Assembly:  `AForge.Video.FFMPEG` (in `AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll`) (from the [documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4ee1742c-44d3-b250-d6aa-90cd2d606611.htm)) (you can find this `AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll` in the `AForge.NET Framework-2.2.5\Release` folder)

If you want to create your *own solution*, make sure you have a reference to `AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll` in your project. Then it should be easy to use the [VideoFileWriter](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4ee1742c-44d3-b250-d6aa-90cd2d606611.htm) class. If you follow the [link](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4ee1742c-44d3-b250-d6aa-90cd2d606611.htm) to the class you will find a very good (and simple example). In the code, they are feeding the VideoFileWriter with `Bitmap image` in a `for`-loop

---

Comment: If anyone is interested, the final resulting video, with "sound effects", can be found on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMZMghjuNT8). Please consider this comment as a demo of the solution only. :o)

Comment: Why did you not answer yesterday? I just needed in it :) But it's great, thank you anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to add audio to created video with aforge library in present time?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried that. When I created my Youtube clip (se link above) I used a friend's video editing software + my home made avi-file and some different sound-clip files.

If you do not have any other video editing software, I _think_ that you can use [VideoLAN Movie Creator - VLMC](http://trac.videolan.org/vlmc/). Please let me know if it works. :-)

Comment: Now I'am using [splicer](http://splicer.codeplex.com/) and it's working, but I don't think that it is a best solution, because of this library is not developing, too old and depend on DrirectShow.

Comment: any full source code sample ? using Namespaces ? which libraries in References ?

Comment: Sample in AForge works for me. I use your code, I use JPG files, and I use this  var imageByteArray = imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(img)); Video generate for me is wrong, not view. Any suggestions ? maybe Image Format ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea. No harm but I believe that it would be easier to answer you if you formulate your own question with your specific problem. Please show your code and output

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer! just a note: If a not found reference run-time error from `AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll` dll throw, you need to copy all the dlls on `C:\Program Files (x86)\AForge.NET\Framework\Externals\ffmpeg\bin` folder to your output directory.

Comment: Is there a x64 version of this method? Using `Aforge.Video.FFMPEG` in a required x64 project, VS says the assembly is mismatched (paraphrased).

Comment: I think you probably should use the constructor of Bitmap to create a Bitmap fromStream, and also Dispose the Bitmap objects you created in the for loop manually, instead of waiting for GC to do it.

Comment: Note that the AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll binary is licensed under GPL v3.

Comment: Did the AForge support mobile platform such as android and ios, I have imported AForge in Unity project, and build as android, it suffer lots of errors.

Comment: I really can't tell. As far as I know, AForge is not .NET core

Answer (score 11):

I found this code in the slicer [samples](http://splicer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Samples&referringTitle=Home), looks pretty close to to what you want:

```
string outputFile = "FadeBetweenImages.wmv";
using (ITimeline timeline = new DefaultTimeline())
{
    IGroup group = timeline.AddVideoGroup(32, 160, 100);
    ITrack videoTrack = group.AddTrack();
    IClip clip1 = videoTrack.AddImage("image1.jpg", 0, 2); // play first image for a little while
    IClip clip2 = videoTrack.AddImage("image2.jpg", 0, 2); // and the next
    IClip clip3 = videoTrack.AddImage("image3.jpg", 0, 2); // and finally the last
    IClip clip4 = videoTrack.AddImage("image4.jpg", 0, 2); // and finally the last
}

  double halfDuration = 0.5;

  // fade out and back in
  group.AddTransition(clip2.Offset - halfDuration, halfDuration, StandardTransitions.CreateFade(), true);
  group.AddTransition(clip2.Offset, halfDuration, StandardTransitions.CreateFade(), false);

  // again
  group.AddTransition(clip3.Offset - halfDuration, halfDuration, StandardTransitions.CreateFade(), true);
  group.AddTransition(clip3.Offset, halfDuration, StandardTransitions.CreateFade(), false);

  // and again
  group.AddTransition(clip4.Offset - halfDuration, halfDuration, StandardTransitions.CreateFade(), true);
  group.AddTransition(clip4.Offset, halfDuration, StandardTransitions.CreateFade(), false);

  // add some audio
  ITrack audioTrack = timeline.AddAudioGroup().AddTrack();

  IClip audio =
     audioTrack.AddAudio("testinput.wav", 0, videoTrack.Duration);

  // create an audio envelope effect, this will:
  // fade the audio from 0% to 100% in 1 second.
  // play at full volume until 1 second before the end of the track
  // fade back out to 0% volume
  audioTrack.AddEffect(0, audio.Duration,
                 StandardEffects.CreateAudioEnvelope(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, audio.Duration));

  // render our slideshow out to a windows media file
  using (
     IRenderer renderer =
        new WindowsMediaRenderer(timeline, outputFile, WindowsMediaProfiles.HighQualityVideo))
  {
     renderer.Render();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've seen that one already but there is just one thing that I can't figure out. I have this important prerequisite with duration, durationOfEachImageMs < 300 ms. Where can I set this very short time in accordance to the above example?

Comment: the last parameter in AddImage is a double, have you tried .3 instead of 2?

Comment: Well, that probably works, but now I run into another issue
`COMException was caught`

Details:
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
  Message=Access is denied.

  Source=DirectShowLib-2005
  ErrorCode=-2147024891
  StackTrace:
       at DirectShowLib.DES.DESError.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 hr)
       at Splicer.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.StartRender()
       at Splicer.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.BeginRender(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at Splicer.Renderer.AbstractRenderer.Render()`


Have you any idea where to go from here?

Comment: Are you sure that Splicer framework will allow 30k IClips created?

Comment: Windows Media Player is a prerrequisite. It's needed install it before.

Answer (score 11):

I could not manage to get the above example to work. However I did find another library that works amazingly well once. Try via NuGet "[accord.extensions.imaging.io](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord.Extensions.Imaging.IO)", then I wrote the following little function:

```
    private void makeAvi(string imageInputfolderName, string outVideoFileName, float fps = 12.0f, string imgSearchPattern = "*.png")
    {   // reads all images in folder 
        VideoWriter w = new VideoWriter(outVideoFileName, 
            new Accord.Extensions.Size(480, 640), fps, true);
        Accord.Extensions.Imaging.ImageDirectoryReader ir = 
            new ImageDirectoryReader(imageInputfolderName, imgSearchPattern);
        while (ir.Position < ir.Length)
        {
            IImage i = ir.Read();
            w.Write(i);
        }
        w.Close();
    }
```

It reads all images from a folder and makes a video out of them.

If you want to make it nicer you could probably read the image dimensions instead of hard coding, but you got the point.

Comment: the library is now called DotImaging

Comment: @dajuric is there an option to integrate audio (text to speech converted) to the video in parallel using the above library?

Comment: @Pranay As the library depends on the OpenCV video API which does not have such options, the answer is no. But, you can generate a video and then invoke ffmpeg to interleave the video with the audio. Notice that, if you wanted to stream a video while it is being constructed you would need to slice it into chunks and then stream it using DASH.

Comment: I've installed Accord through NuGet but I can't get this code to work.  It's not recognizing the VideoWriter class.

Answer (score 8):

The **FFMediaToolkit** is a good solution in 2020, with .NET Core support.

https://github.com/radek-k/FFMediaToolkit

> FFMediaToolkit is a cross-platform .NET Standard library for creating and reading video files. It uses native FFmpeg libraries by the FFmpeg.Autogen bindings.

The README of the library has a nice example for the question asked.

```cs
// You can set there codec, bitrate, frame rate and many other options.
var settings = new VideoEncoderSettings(width: 1920, height: 1080, framerate: 30, codec: VideoCodec.H264);
settings.EncoderPreset = EncoderPreset.Fast;
settings.CRF = 17;
var file = MediaBuilder.CreateContainer(@"C:\videos\example.mp4").WithVideo(settings).Create();
while(file.Video.FramesCount < 300)
{
    file.Video.AddFrame(/*Your code*/);
}
file.Dispose(); // MediaOutput ("file" variable) must be disposed when encoding is completed. You can use `using() { }` block instead.
```

Comment: Big disclaimer - this library should not be used for production use

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution for creating a video from an image sequence using Visual Studio using C#.

My starting point was "Hauns TM"'s answer below but my requirements were more basic than theirs so this solution might be more appropriated for less advanced users ( like myself )

Libraries:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
```

You can get the FFMPEG libarary by searching for FFMPEG in "Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for a Solution..."

The variables that I passed into the function are:

- outputFileName     = `"C://outputFolder//outputMovie.avi"`
- inputImageSequence = 
  `["C://inputFolder//image_001.avi",
  "C://inputFolder//image_002.avi",
  "C://inputFolder//image_003.avi",
  "C://inputFolder//image_004.avi"]`

Function:

```
private void videoMaker( string outputFileName , string[] inputImageSequence)
{
  int width = 1920;
  int height = 1080;
  var framRate = 25;

  using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
  {
    // create new video file
    vFWriter.Open(outputFileName, width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.Raw);

    foreach (var imageLocation in inputImageSequence)
    {
      Bitmap imageFrame = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageLocation) as Bitmap;
      vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(imageFrame);
    }
    vFWriter.Close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like many of these answers are a bit obsolete year 2020, so I add my thoughts.

I have been working on the same problem and have published the .NET Core project **Time Lapse Creator** on GitHub: https://github.com/pekspro/TimeLapseCreator It shows how to add information on extra frame (like a timestamp for instance), background audio, title screen, fading and some more. And then **ffmpeg** is used to make the rendering. This is done in this function:

```
// Render video from a list of images, add background audio and a thumbnail image.
private async Task RenderVideoAsync(int framesPerSecond, List<string> images, string ffmpgPath,
        string audioPath, string thumbnailImagePath, string outPath,
        double videoFadeInDuration = 0, double videoFadeOutDuration = 0,
        double audioFadeInDuration = 0, double audioFadeOutDuration = 0)
{
    string fileListName = Path.Combine(OutputPath, "framelist.txt");
    var fileListContent = images.Select(a => $"file '{a}'{Environment.NewLine}duration 1");

    await File.WriteAllLinesAsync(fileListName, fileListContent);

    TimeSpan vidLengthCalc = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(images.Count / ((double)framesPerSecond));
    int coverId = -1;
    int audioId = -1;
    int framesId = 0;
    int nextId = 1;

    StringBuilder inputParameters = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder outputParameters = new StringBuilder();

    inputParameters.Append($"-r {framesPerSecond} -f concat -safe 0 -i {fileListName} ");

    outputParameters.Append($"-map {framesId} ");

    if(videoFadeInDuration > 0 || videoFadeOutDuration > 0)
    {
        List<string> videoFilterList = new List<string>();
        if (videoFadeInDuration > 0)
        {
            //Assume we fade in from first second.
            videoFilterList.Add($"fade=in:start_time={0}s:duration={videoFadeInDuration.ToString("0", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}s");
        }

        if (videoFadeOutDuration > 0)
        {
            //Assume we fade out to last second.
            videoFilterList.Add($"fade=out:start_time={(vidLengthCalc.TotalSeconds - videoFadeOutDuration).ToString("0.000", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}s:duration={videoFadeOutDuration.ToString("0.000", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}s");
        }

        string videoFilterString = string.Join(',', videoFilterList);

        outputParameters.Append($"-filter:v:{framesId} \"{videoFilterString}\" ");
    }

    if (thumbnailImagePath != null)
    {
        coverId = nextId;
        nextId++;

        inputParameters.Append($"-i {thumbnailImagePath} ");

        outputParameters.Append($"-map {coverId} ");
        outputParameters.Append($"-c:v:{coverId} copy -disposition:v:{coverId} attached_pic ");
    }

    if (audioPath != null)
    {
        audioId = nextId;
        nextId++;

        inputParameters.Append($"-i {audioPath} ");
        outputParameters.Append($"-map {audioId} ");

        if(audioFadeInDuration <= 0 && audioFadeOutDuration <= 0)
        {
            // If no audio fading, just copy as it is.
            outputParameters.Append($"-c:a copy ");
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> audioEffectList = new List<string>();
            if(audioFadeInDuration > 0)
            {
                //Assume we fade in from first second.
                audioEffectList.Add($"afade=in:start_time={0}s:duration={audioFadeInDuration.ToString("0", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}s");
            }

            if (audioFadeOutDuration > 0)
            {
                //Assume we fade out to last second.
                audioEffectList.Add($"afade=out:start_time={(vidLengthCalc.TotalSeconds - audioFadeOutDuration).ToString("0.000", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}s:duration={audioFadeOutDuration.ToString("0.000", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}s");
            }

            string audioFilterString = string.Join(',', audioEffectList);

            outputParameters.Append($"-filter:a \"{audioFilterString}\" ");
        }
    }

    int milliseconds = vidLengthCalc.Milliseconds;
    int seconds = vidLengthCalc.Seconds;
    int minutes = vidLengthCalc.Minutes;
    var hours = (int)vidLengthCalc.TotalHours;

    string durationString = $"{hours:D}:{minutes:D2}:{seconds:D2}.{milliseconds:D3}";

    outputParameters.Append($"-c:v:{framesId} libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -to {durationString} {outPath} -y ");
        
    string parameters = inputParameters.ToString() + outputParameters.ToString();

    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var outputLog = new List<string>();

            using (var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                FileName = ffmpgPath,
                Arguments = parameters,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                // ffmpeg send everything to the error output, standard output is not used.
                RedirectStandardError = true
                },
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            })
            {
                process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    outputLog.Add(e.Data.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString());
                };

                process.Start();

                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                process.WaitForExit();

                if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"ffmpeg failed error exit code {process.ExitCode}. Log: {string.Join(Environment.NewLine, outputLog)}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Exit code: {process.ExitCode}");
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Win32Exception )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oh no, failed to start ffmpeg. Have you downloaded and copied ffmpeg.exe to the output folder?");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Video was successfully created. It is availible at: " + Path.GetFullPath(outPath));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is based on Splicer.Net library.Took me ages to understand how that library works. 
Make sure that your fps(frame per second )is correct. By the way standard 24 f/s.

In my case I have 15 images and I now that I need 7 seconds video-> so fps =2.
Fps may vary according to platform...or developer usage.

```
public bool CreateVideo(List<Bitmap> bitmaps, string outputFile, double fps)
        {
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            if (bitmaps == null || bitmaps.Count == 0) return false;
            try
            {
                using (ITimeline timeline = new DefaultTimeline(fps))
                {
                    IGroup group = timeline.AddVideoGroup(32, width, height);
                    ITrack videoTrack = group.AddTrack();

                    int i = 0;
                    double miniDuration = 1.0 / fps;
                    foreach (var bmp in bitmaps)
                    {
                        IClip clip = videoTrack.AddImage(bmp, 0, i * miniDuration, (i + 1) * miniDuration);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(++i);

                    }
                    timeline.AddAudioGroup();
                    IRenderer renderer = new WindowsMediaRenderer(timeline, outputFile, WindowsMediaProfiles.HighQualityVideo);
                    renderer.Render();
                }
            }
            catch { return false; }
            return true;
        }
```

Hope this helps.