# Splicer Libraries are not supporting the mp3 format

Tags: c#, .net, windows, video, mp3

I'm a trying to create a simple application in C#.NET that can generate a video file from a stream of Images and an audio file.
I chooses the [Splicer](http://splicer.codeplex.com) and its working perfectly fine with my part of code. However when I try to put an mp3 audio format it shows an **ERROR:An invalid media type was specified.**
I scanned the Splicer forum but didn't get anything useful.
Any kind of help is appreciated.
Here is a simple code:

```
        using (ITimeline timeline = new DefaultTimeline())
        {
            IGroup audioGroup = timeline.AddAudioGroup();
            ITrack rootTrack = audioGroup.AddTrack();
            rootTrack.AddAudio("testinput.mp3");

            using (
                WindowsMediaRenderer renderer =
                    new WindowsMediaRenderer(timeline, "output.avi", WindowsMediaProfiles.LowQualityAudio))
            {
                renderer.Render();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This sounds like a feature request for Splicer, or for you to figure out how to convert MP3 -> WAV

Comment: I can convert the mp3 > wav without any issue but I want my app compatible with mp3 format. The code I posted is from the Splicer website itself which indicates that mp3 might be compatible with it. But I don't know where the things are getting wrong

Comment: What I was saying is that this question is probably better directed at the Splicer folks

Comment: I already tried but they didn't respond. I saw here some SOLVED threads regarding Splicer and Image to Video topic, So I thought might someone has experience with this issue.

Comment: did you tried *AForge* ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744026/image-sequence-to-video-stream/12376324?noredirect=1