# The type or namespace name 'ImageEntitiesContainer' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ffmpeg, namespaces, aforge

I'm trying to build a C#.NET application from the source code of a solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744026/image-sequence-to-video-stream/12376324#answer-12376324).

I've already added a reference to **AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll**, but I am still getting the following error:

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'ImageEntitiesContainer' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\CSharp\ImagesToVideo\Program.cs 56  40  ImagesToVideo

I searched for this error and found a few posts, but nothing that helps. I tried changing the target framework from my default ".NET Framework 4.5" to some other frameworks: ".NET Framework 2.0", ".NET Framework 3.0", ".NET Framework 4.0", but without any success. Does anyone have any idea why I am still getting this error?

Here is my full source code:

```
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AForge.Video.FFMPEG
{
public class MovieMaker
{

    public void Start()
    {
        var startDate = DateTime.Parse("12 Mar 2012");
        var endDate = DateTime.Parse("13 Aug 2012");

        CreateMovie(startDate, endDate);
    }


    /*THIS CODE BLOCK IS COPIED*/

    public Bitmap ToBitmap(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        var returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(returnImage);

        return bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap ReduceBitmap(Bitmap original, int reducedWidth, int reducedHeight)
    {
        var reduced = new Bitmap(reducedWidth, reducedHeight);
        using (var dc = Graphics.FromImage(reduced))
        {
            // you might want to change properties like
            dc.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            dc.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, reducedWidth, reducedHeight), new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        return reduced;
    }

    /*END OF COPIED CODE BLOCK*/


    private void CreateMovie(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        int width = 320;
        int height = 240;
        var framRate = 200;

        using (var container = new ImageEntitiesContainer())
        {
            //a LINQ-query for getting the desired images
            var query = from d in container.ImageSet
                        where d.Date >= startDate && d.Date <= endDate
                        select d;

            // create instance of video writer
            using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
            {
                // create new video file
                vFWriter.Open("nameOfMyVideoFile.avi", width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.Raw);

                var imageEntities = query.ToList();

                //loop throught all images in the collection
                foreach (var imageEntity in imageEntities)
                {
                    //what's the current image data?
                    var imageByteArray = imageEntity.Data;
                    var bmp = ToBitmap(imageByteArray);
                    var bmpReduced = ReduceBitmap(bmp, width, height);

                    vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bmpReduced);
                }
                vFWriter.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: When you right click on `ImageEntitiesContainer` do you see an option titled `Resolve`?

Comment: Unfortunately no I don't see an option to "Resolve" after right-clicking on ImageEntitiesContainer.

Comment: I can't seem to find `ImageEntitiesContainer` anywhere in the AForge.NET source, are you sure that class even exists?

Comment: Well no I'm not sure, however others in the [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744026/image-sequence-to-video-stream/12376324#answer-12376324) I linked to seemed to have got it working.

Comment: I think the `ImageEntitiesContainer` is an undocumented class in the linked SO answer, only. It seems to hold a number of `ImageSet` objects, which are fetched from the database in the example. You should easily be able to construct your own `ImageEntitiesContainer` class, in the linked example it is only used as a data container.

Comment: Thanks Anders, your response helps a lot, since I am still new to C#.NET and programming in general. But this will help get me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ImageEntitiesContainer is **not a class** but a **Data Source**.You can figure it out in the LINQ-query code：

```
using (var container = new ImageEntitiesContainer())
{
    //a LINQ-query for getting the desired images
    var query = from d in container.ImageSet
                where d.Date >= startDate && d.Date <= endDate
                select d;
```

**ImageEntitiesContainer** is the **ADO.Net Entity Data Model** which you have to create it by yourself.

**ImageSet** is a table in ImageEntitiesContainer.

The picture was captured from the link you provided：

[image]

Comment: Thanks Angus, I thought maybe I could still get the code to work and was expecting an error about not being able to find a database if that was the issue. I guess I'll have to setup a way to capture all JPG files in a folder and use that as my source, since I won't be using a database.

Comment: Yes @KeithJ,you can follow it or use your own way to get data.Good luck.