# Save WriteableBitmap C# WPF video stream to file

Tags: c#, wpf, image, realsense, writablebitmap

I have a intel realsense camera that is showing video "streams" on WPF Image based on https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/csharp/cs-tutorial-2-capture/Window.xaml.cs

I want to write a video every-time there is a new image.

```
imgDepth.Source = new WriteableBitmap(p.Width, p.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null);
```

When I close the program, I will have a video (.avi, mp4..). How can I achieve this. I was thinking of using VideoWriter Class of EMGUCV library. Or is there some easier way? thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify what are you looking for? it seems like you already have most of the knowlage what it "means" to create a Video. You need a Format you want to store your images in and you need a lib to transform your stream of images to a file that is encoded for this format.

Comment: I basically need help how to know whenever there is a new image on the WPF image control, to write frame to a video and save video on close. I am still new to c# so how can I achieve this in code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744026/image-sequence-to-video-stream