# Convert image sequence to MP4 file using .Net Core and C# on Azure Storage Blobs

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, video-processing

I have an API with a POST method which captures images and stores them to a blob container on Azure. These images will make up a sequence of frames for a video file once ready to process. I have another endpoint that my application calls when it is ready to process the sequence and get back a video file.

I have everything in place and ready for video processing but I am stuck on how to achieve what I thought would be very simple! Since my endpoint runs in .NET Core I cannot use any legacy .Net libraries and since I am deploying to an Azure WebApp (Windows OS) that may need to scale up/out I cannot install anything other than pre-compiled .Net Core compatible Nuget packages on the hardware as part of my deployment from DevOps.

I can't find any good libraries or examples that run in this scenario. I've run into issues trying to use anything related to GDI+ or FFMPEG...

Was hoping to find something similar to **SixLabors.ImageSharp**

*I have a list of all the images in order and ready to be processed like so:*

```
var frames = new List<Image>();

// (Removed for brevity) Retrieve images from blobs & append to frame list...

foreach(var frame in frames)
{
    // Convert frames/sequence to video file
}

// Save to blob storage as .mp4
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my experience, the solution to convert image sequence to a video streaming or file is normally to use some popular libraries like `ffmpeg` or `libav` to do that.

If you search for some keywords like `C# ffmpeg images video` or `C# libav images video`, you will get much useful content to help realizing it, as below, there are few threads you can refer to.

1. [Image sequence to video stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744026/image-sequence-to-video-stream)
2. [Converting Images into Video using C#](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/523429/convertingplusimagesplusintoplusvideoplususingplus)
3. [tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg](https://github.com/tomaszzmuda/Xabe.FFmpeg)

And then, you can get the video streaming or file to upload to Azure Blob Storage as  a block blob, please follow the offical tutorial [`Quickstart: Azure Blob storage client library for .NET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) to know how to use Azure Storage SDK for .NET standard and the key class in C# is [`CloudBlockBlob Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob?view=azure-dotnet) which functions [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.beginuploadfromfile?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_BeginUploadFromFile_System_String_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_)`BeginUploadFromFile` for video file or [`BeginUploadFromStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.beginuploadfromstream?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_BeginUploadFromStream_System_IO_Stream_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_) for video stream.

But there is an issue about your app deployment. Due to the limitation of [`Azure Web App sandbox`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) about [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) as the figure below, you can not deploy any app used GDI system call to Azure WebApp.

[image]

So a normal recommended Azure service for your app is Azure VM.

---

Update:

If you considered to use dotNet Core to realize it, I suggested that you can try to use [Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro) which be based on Docker and no limits for GDI. Also, [Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/) is the other choice for realizing your needs in any language. And I wish you will complete your evaluation.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I actually went through all 3 of those links already. As you mentioned the main problem I have is attempting to do this using a WebApp and not a VM. I wanted to avoid having to manage a VM in my scenario and was hoping I could find a solution that I could leverage that is easy to deploy/scale using a managed solution. Possibly even cross-platform using .Net Core. I'm looking at 3rd party services offering API's right now that may actually allow me to do this. The main contender is Translodeit: https://transloadit.com/ I will update this answer once my evaluation is complete.

Comment: Thank you Peter! The Azure Batch option is actually very compelling! For anyone interested I found a good video on it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvX0IeFMmCE) as well as a starter project [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-parallel-dotnet) and the associated code [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-dotnet-ffmpeg-tutorial). For the Transcodeit option they have a compelling endpoint [here](https://transloadit.com/demos/video-encoding/generate-a-video-from-image-sequence/) - I may end up using the Azure Batch solution as it is the most flexible.